# Get ID from last insert into table

Tags: php, mysql

Im inserting into multiple tables , and need to get the ID from the last insert into table1 and use that as a variable in the insert for table 2.

The IDs is auto incremented.

The query's will be run once a submit button has been clicked in a form.

Query's:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (Text) VALUES ($T1text);";
$sql = "INSERT INTO table2 (table1ID,Text) VALUES ($table1id, $T2text);";


table1 {id,Text}
table2 {id,table1.id,Text}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`?

Comment: `mysqli_insert_id()` for mysqli, `mysql_insert_id()` for mysql and `lastInsertId()` for PDO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a PHP function for that (Decprecated, Removed in 7.0 !)
Or the according mysql/mysqli/pdo functions.

Solutions

PHP (Deprecated)

Example

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('mydb');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Mysql/Mysqli/PDO

Mysqli
    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
    VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

PDO

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
// use exec() because no results are returned
$conn->exec($sql);
$last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp